# Display data based on multiple dropdown selection in Flutter

Tags: java, flutter, dart, dropdown

I have a question regarding the dropdown usage. Currently, I have two different dropdown where if the view is month, it will display this two dropdown for user to choose the month and year. For example, if user choose month august and year 2021, the display data should be based on the selection. But the problem is, for example I choose month 'aug' followed by year '2021', it will always display the data for 'jan' because that was the default value for the month.

The thing is I'm not sure on how to get the value of onchanged from the first dropdown to put inside the second dropdown. Here is my code:

```
class DropdownItem {
  DropdownItem({required this.name, required this.value});
  final String name;
  final String value;
}

class DropdownItemYear {
  DropdownItemYear({required this.nameYear, required this.valueYear});
  final String nameYear;
  final String valueYear;
}

class ExactTimeDropdown extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExactTimeDropdown({
    required Key key,
    required this.exactTime,
    required this.function,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final String exactTime;
  final Function function;
  @override
  ExactTimeDropdownState createState() => ExactTimeDropdownState();
}

class ExactTimeDropdownState extends State<ExactTimeDropdown> {
  final key = GlobalKey();
  String? valueYear = '';
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  List<DropdownItem> dropdownExactTimeItems = <DropdownItem>[];
  List<DropdownItemYear> dropdownYearItems = <DropdownItemYear>[];
  String? dropdownExactTimeLabel = '';
  String? dropdownYearLabel = '';
  
// default value is january
  String? value = 'jan';
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    if (widget.exactTime == 'year') {
      dropdownExactTimeLabel = '2021';
      dropdownExactTimeItems = [
        DropdownItem(name: '2021', value: '2021'),
        DropdownItem(name: '2022', value: '2022'),
      ];
    } else if (widget.exactTime == 'month') {
      dropdownExactTimeLabel = 'jan';
      dropdownExactTimeItems = [
        DropdownItem(name: 'Jan', value: 'jan'),
        DropdownItem(name: 'Feb', value: 'feb'),
        DropdownItem(name: 'March', value: 'mar'),
        DropdownItem(name: 'April', value: 'apr'),
        DropdownItem(name: 'May', value: 'may'),
        DropdownItem(name: 'Jun', value: 'jun'),
        DropdownItem(name: 'July', value: 'july'),
        DropdownItem(name: 'Aug', value: 'aug'),
        DropdownItem(name: 'Sept', value: 'sept'),
        DropdownItem(name: 'Oct', value: 'oct'),
        DropdownItem(name: 'Nov', value: 'nov'),
        DropdownItem(name: 'Dec', value: 'dec'),
      ];
      dropdownYearLabel = '2021';
      dropdownYearItems = [
        DropdownItemYear(nameYear: '202a1', valueYear: '2021'),
        DropdownItemYear(nameYear: '2022', valueYear: '2022'),
      ];
    } else if (widget.exactTime == 'threemonth') {
      dropdownExactTimeLabel = 'janmarch';
      dropdownExactTimeItems = [
        DropdownItem(name: 'Jan - Mar', value: 'janmarch'),
        DropdownItem(name: 'Apr - Jun', value: 'aprjun'),
        DropdownItem(name: 'July - Sept', value: 'julysept'),
        DropdownItem(name: 'Oct - Dec', value: 'octdec'),
      ];
      dropdownYearLabel = '2021';
      dropdownYearItems = [
        DropdownItemYear(nameYear: '202a1', valueYear: '2021'),
        DropdownItemYear(nameYear: '2022', valueYear: '2022'),
      ];
    } else if (widget.exactTime == 'sixmonth') {
      dropdownExactTimeLabel = 'janjune';
      dropdownExactTimeItems = [
        DropdownItem(name: 'Jan - June', value: 'janjune'),
        DropdownItem(name: 'July - Dec', value: 'julydec'),
      ];
      dropdownYearLabel = '2021';
      dropdownYearItems = [
        DropdownItemYear(nameYear: '202a1', valueYear: '2021'),
        DropdownItemYear(nameYear: '2022', valueYear: '2022'),
      ];
    }

// if the exact time is year, just display one dropdown
    return (widget.exactTime == 'year')
        ? SizedBox(
            width: 100,
            child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
              style: kDropdownText,
              value: dropdownExactTimeLabel,
              items: dropdownExactTimeItems.map((DropdownItem dropdownItems) {
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: dropdownItems.value,
                  child: Text(dropdownItems.name),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  dropdownExactTimeLabel = value;
                  widget.function(value, valueYear);
                });
              },
            ),
          )
// if the exact time is month, display two dropdown
        : Row(
            children: [
              // dropdown for month selection
              SizedBox(
                width: 100,
                child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                  style: kDropdownText,
                  value: dropdownExactTimeLabel,
                  items:
                      dropdownExactTimeItems.map((DropdownItem dropdownItems) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: dropdownItems.value,
                      child: Text(dropdownItems.name),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      dropdownExactTimeLabel = value;
                      widget.function(value, valueYear);
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 20,
              ),
              // dropdown for year selection
              SizedBox(
                width: 100,
                child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                  style: kDropdownText,
                  value: dropdownYearLabel,
                  items: dropdownYearItems
                      .map((DropdownItemYear dropdownItemsYear) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: dropdownItemsYear.valueYear,
                      child: Text(dropdownItemsYear.nameYear),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  onChanged: (valueYear) {
                    setState(() {
                      dropdownYearLabel = valueYear;
                      // here for value, should get the value from the first dropdown, not the default value
                      widget.function(value, valueYear);
                    });
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
  }
}
```

Is there any possible way to get the value from the other dropdown? I'm sorry if my question sounds dumb but I've stuck on this for few days. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to store selected values from dropdowns in different variables in your state class, and create a method that react to changes and rebuilds the UI.

Comment: I tried to create new variable to store the current value every time the onChanged function is triggered and it works!  Thank you for your help!!